# How to keep django app running in the background within the vagrant?

Tags: django, ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 host headless Server.

Using root user, I `vagrant up` a VM that is using VirtualBox.

Inside this VM, is a Django Python 3 app.

Every time I `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` this VM, I need to run `sudo service gunicorn start`.

If I exit from the vagrant ssh, and then switch to another user, the app dies.

How do I maintain this Django app running from the VM permanently?

If the host machine has to reboot for whatever reason, how can the Django app automatically run itself?

In summary:

1. how to allow vagrant and the gunicorn inside the VM run for a very long time while I switch between users in the host OS?
2. Is there a way to automatically revive the vagrant and the gunicorn inside, whenever the host OS is rebooted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

`sudo service gunicorn start &`

The `&` sign will make your command to run on a different process then the terminal one, so you can close the terminal without closing the gunicorn.

By the way, this is not a vagrant related, it happens on all linux-like terminals.

For your second question, you need to use something like [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html) to handle this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the `&`. As for supervisord, I am a bit of a noob. You able to give a slightly more detailed answer?

Comment: @KimStacks It's a wide topic and I can cover everything as a side note on this question, I recommend you to start from the docs, if you have specific question please post it :) please consider accepting my answer

Comment: Okay. I started a new question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673662/how-to-use-supervisord-to-auto-restart-vagrant-and-then-restart-gunicorn-with-th